# Result cannot be changed upon changing gridview page number

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When I was changing page number, I was getting error

```
"The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."
```

But afterwards, I searched and try to put this code in PageIndexChanging even, still it isn't working :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Originally, when user prompts to page, I am showing all data on gridview, then user can search data, and upon clicking Search button, below code is executing :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now, dt2 = DateTime.Now;
    Connection.getCon();
    try
    {
         dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox3.Text);
         dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text).AddDays(1);
        lblError.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        lblError.Visible = true;
    }


    string cmd = "select * from tblLogs where (users like '%"+TextBox1.Text.Trim()+"%') and (request like '%"+TextBox2.Text.Trim()+"%') and (requesttime>='"+dt1+"') and (requesttime<'"+dt2+"') ";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataView dv= (DataView) SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
    GridView1.DataSource= dv;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

}
```

Now, I am not getting any error, but still page is not changing and staying on 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you assigned that `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` to the gridview ??

Comment: try to add `AllowPaging="True"` then set `PageSize="50"`

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: I tried even that, and Allowpaging property true only. but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong property in your PageIndexChanging event, it should be [PageIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindex.aspx) instead of SelectedIndex:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```